# Масштабирование и адаптация блока под телефоны

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать, чтобы на телефоне отображалась только желтая выделенная часть? Остальной фон (body) обрезался?

Общее понятие: Чтобы главным отображался всегда желтый блок, а в лишней пустой части экрана уже был дополнительный фон, если для него имеется место.

[image: Только желтая часть должна отображаться на телефоне]

Comment: Про какой фон body вы говорите?

Comment: body {background: ....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: yellow;   
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
    body {
        background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kb9rVUDpECZPWm2QQlaZLcCRYP_3YGzsdmk5zVRoaDX77xaVWohr-hsgO9A1911HqHo=w720-h310) no-repeat center center / cover;
    }
}

.block-yellow{    
    background: yellow;
    padding: 25px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-yellow"></div>
```

Comment: Что значит *{ }?

Comment: Я сделал этот @media screen... На телефоне все равно отступы, правда, уже на чуть-чуть меньше

Comment: @YaYa - селектор, соответствующий любому элементу на странице

Comment: @YaYa - я не подгонял под ваши размеры, а сделал не большой пример

Comment: Я понял, а как сделать, чтобы блок желтый был почти на весь экран? Какой параметр менять?

Comment: если в ширину - необходимо обнулять отступы у блока (ов) родителя. Если  в высоту, например задать блоку min-height: 100vh;